# How to make a photo collage using html and css?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a photo collage using html and css.
The pictures i want to use are of variable height and width,but they must be fixed in the page without gaps.
How do i achieve this?Please help..!!

Comment: What have  you tried so far? What is you HTML markup?

Comment: I have used rows of divs and used float:left on them.But all divs are of same height and width ...but the pics i am using are of variable height and width

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to do this in css only you have to create divs for every column, and float those columns (but it messes up order of images).

Alternatively, you can use jquery plugin like this [one](http://masonry.desandro.com/) .